# How do I get the middle 45% of a table on SQL?

Tags: sql

I already have two tables. One containing the Top 5% (#Top5) and another containing the bottom 50% (#Bottom50). I also have a table containing all 100% (#Total)... Is there a way I can use these to make a third table with the remaining 45%? If I join each row has its own specific userid, so that is what it would be on.

Comment: Something like [`MINUS`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php)?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? The syntax for limiting and offset varies widely among them.

Comment: MINUS is product specific.

Comment: Why do you need these other tables at all? With the 100% table you have the top 5% and bottom 50% and other 45% implicitely already.

Comment: Note: Temporary tables require extra resources to create and maintain the data within them. Are you sure you actually need them? Or could you simply query against your #Total table?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each row has a unique id, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from #Total t
where not exists (select 1 from #Bottom50 b where b.userid = t.userid) and
      not exists (select 1 from #Top5 tt where tt.userid = t.userid)
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

You can add a `create table as` or `into` statement to actually create the new table.  The specific syntax depends on the database.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what SQL dialect you use, there should be set-based operators such as `UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`/`MINUS`. If you don't care about retaining duplicate values in the table, the last operator can be used to get what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM #Total
EXCEPT SELECT * FROM #Top5
EXCEPT SELECT * FROM #Bottom50
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, since `EXCEPT` is defined in section 7.10 (pg. 196) of the SQL1992 standard I can assert that all modern dialects should support `EXCEPT`. If they don't, I'd suggest  they are outdated or non-standard. http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: Postgre, MySQL, SQL Server, Sybase and Oracle support intersect and except/minus... and i think there are many more DBMS which do...not all of course

Comment: @CoOnSQL . . . The issue is *specifically* `except`.  Neither Oracle nor MySQL support `except` (the former calls it `MINUS`) and the latter doesn't have an equivalent construct.  Postgres (naturally) and SQL Server (somewhat more surprisingly but probably because Sybase originally did) support the ANSI standard keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Combination of LEFT JOIN and IS NULL in the where clause should do the trick and should work on many platforms:

```
SELECT  T.*
FROM    #Total T
        LEFT JOIN #Top5 T5 ON T.userid = T5.userid
        LEFT JOIN #Bottom50 B50 ON T.userid = B50.userid
WHERE   T5.userid IS NULL
        AND B50.userid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Total
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #Top5 t5 WHERE t5.PKey = #total.PKey)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #Bottom50 t50 WHERE t50.PKey = #total.PKey)
```

Comment: Please specify dbms, since non-standard SQL is used.

Comment: TOP 1 1 is a very nice method if you just want to know "is there any row".. have a look a this picuture (query costs relative to the batch): http://s10.postimg.org/tb35kj9dl/top1.jpg

Comment: When [NOT] EXISTS, does any dbms even bother what's selected in the sub-select?